# Data standards for election results

Tags: standards, elections

I've found the schemas for the [Election Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Election_Markup_Language), and this relatively thin json effort https://github.com/wnyc/election_california_2012/blob/master/examples/sample.json

Are there any other widely used data standards or APIs for election results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't widely used, because we just started working on it this year, but our Knight Foundation project, OpenElections, is developing specs for election results in the United States. You can see the latest specification [on our Github wiki](https://github.com/openelections/specs/wiki/Results-Data-Spec-Version-2). We also have a format for [election metadata](https://github.com/openelections/specs/wiki/Elections-Data-Spec-Version-2). Project details at [openelections.net](http://blog.openelections.net/).

Answer (score 5):

I've also found [IEEE P1622.2 - Standard for Election Results Reporting Data Interchange Format](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/project/1622.2.html).